# Zorn Lemma and the set of Real Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've studied the Zorn Lemma and i'm trying to apply it to the set of real numbers.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is compliant to the lemma then i can define a maxima.
But $\mathbb{R}$ has no upper bound, is it correct to assert the maxima in this case is $+\infty $ ?

Comment: If you understand why it doesn't apply to $\Bbb N$, then $\Bbb N$ is a chain in $\Bbb R$ that has no upper bound.

Comment: there are chains in $\mathbb R$ that aren't bounded w.r.t the usual order. Perhaps, you can find another order for which every chain in $\mathbb R$ is bounded.

Comment: In fact $\Bbb R$ is a chain in $\Bbb R$ with no upper bound, so the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma are not satisfied.